# is there way to clone the column of the table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have tried to clone the existing column from the table. I don't know where i made the mistake in my code.

```js
    $(function() {
      $("#we").click(function() {
        $("table tr:last").after('<tr></tr>');
        $('table tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function() {
          $('table tr:last').append('<td><input type="text"/></td>');
        });
      });
      $('#addcolumn').click(function() {
        var ae = $('table tr').find('td:eq(1)').clone();
        $('table td').each(function() {
          $('table tr').append(ae);
        });

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id='we' type="button" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" value="AddColumn" id='addcolumn' />
```

Comment: can you explain what are trying to do...on submit you have two text boxes coming up and on add column i dont understnad whats happening

Comment: You say you don't know where you made a mistake, can you provide some context as to what the mistake is? makes it a little easier for us to pinpoint the issue and help you out.

Comment: submit button goes to create new rows. I want to clone the column of the table when i click the addcolumn button

Comment: @Turk, addcolumn button.

Comment: And what is the column number you want to clone?

Comment: last column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You're ovecomplicating this. Just loop over all the `tr` elements and append a clone of the first `td`:

```
$('#addcolumn').click(function() {

    $('table tr').each(function() {
      $(this).append($(this).find('td:first').clone());
    });

});
```

Live example below.

```js
$(function() {
      $("#we").click(function() {
        $("table tr:last").after('<tr></tr>');
        $('table tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function() {
          $('table tr:last').append('<td><input type="text"/></td>');
        });
      });
      $('#addcolumn').click(function() {
        
        $('table tr').each(function() {
          $(this).append($(this).find('td:first').clone());
        });

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id='we' type="button" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" value="AddColumn" id='addcolumn' />
```

Comment: basic code, yes. But there's a way to do it more comfortable. If you need heavy data operations wrapped inside a table I would recommend you to use the jQuery datatable plugin. It is especially made for this. It is worth to learn it. Or, if you want much more data manipulation/filterung in a table view, then you should look at the KendoUI Grid (the opensource edition is free and have also all advantages). KendoUI ships plugins for many JavaScript frontend frameworks like jQuery, Angular, etc.. It is also worth looking at it.

Comment: @alpham8 - if that was a comment on my answer (I dont think it is) then you're welcome to comment here. If it was a comment to the OP a better place would be on the question itself. Comments here are for discussing improving my answer, and my answer does not include "Use a giant library for this simple task"

Comment: @Jamiec Well, yes, it is a comment on your answer. Take it as an addition to your answer. And also, please think different. Librariers aren't just "huge". They have their sense. And it isn't the question whether using a library or not on small projects. You should use the same library on every project. That point was discussed a lot in forums etc.. A library is a good thing for a common task. Because it is well tested and it thinks of issues that you may dont think of at the moment. So, yes, it is better to use a "huge" library in most of the cases.

Comment: @alpham8 sorry but no, this is not a comment on my answer. if you want to pose an answer which is "use datatables plugin" then that is fine, but it has nothing whatsoever to do with my answer.